# Read Cookies from BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, cookies

Is there a way to download the cookies to my desktop, so I can read them?

Right now I am using an mds-stand alone simulator with OS 5.0.0 BlackBerry 9520, and after the cookies are saved, I go to simulator's directory where I pull dump file, i.e.

```
Research In Motion\BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 5.0.0\5.0.0.741 (9520)\9520-fs.dmp
```

Then with a binary editor I can view the cookies content (user, password etc).

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is useful for speeding up this sort of thing, simply view the cookie contents and any other API information in the packet trace as it arrives.

In case you are using HTTPS then you can still view the packet information using software like [charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Comment: It Works in both sniffers from you and Arhimed, but they are requering me to look for physical cookie. I will look if this can be possible. Thanks

Comment: When you say physical cookie do you mean contained in a file? If so, that's only in a file because the web browser software has taken the Set-Cookie header from the HTTP packet and saved it that way for later use. There shouldn't be a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using https, then you can use some network sniffer to monitor http activity of the simulator process. For instance, take a look at stand-alone edition of [HttpAnalyzer](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/features.html#Monitor%20System-Wide/Single/Multi%20Process).